# creating a function for for-loop across specific set of ranges in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, range

How can you loop across multiple different ranges. for example say i want to run a for loop for specific set of ranges

**1 to 2, 4 to 6 and 10 to 13,**

I don't know the exact final number so maybe a function might be useful.

The standard method of

```
for i in range(1,2) + range (4,6) + range (10,13)
```

I should have this

```
[1,4,5,6,10,11,13]
```

My question is, this is not so efficient, if i don't know the total number of ranges am covering, and I can't even create this as a function without so many parameters.

so if i want to have something like this

```
for i in range(a,b) + range (c,d) + range (e,f), .....
```

but as a simple function
Can someone help with an efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: The call range(1,2) returns 1 not 1 and 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the ranges with itertools:

```
from itertools import chain

total_range = chain(range(1,2), range(4,6), range(10,13))

print(list(total_range))
#[1, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12]
```

Here is another solution with a function that returns a generator:

```
def total_range(lst):
    return (i for tup in lst for i in range(tup[0], tup[1]))

list_of_ranges = [(1,2), (4,6), (10,13)]
print(list(total_range(list_of_ranges)))
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem. I need it as a function

Comment: What are the arguments for your desired function? A list of ranges? If so, you can easily incorporate this code in a function.

Comment: @mufty__py See my amended answer. I created a function that takes in a list of tuples that correspond to a discontinuous range and returns a generator that can be used like a range.

Answer (score 4):

Simple, though most likely the least efficient solution is to use a nested for loop,

```
def multi_range_loop(ranges):

    all_values = []
    for rg in ranges:
        for i in range(rg[0], rg[1]):
            all_values.append(i)
    print(all_values)

my_ranges = [[1,3],[4,7],[10,14]]
multi_range_loop(my_ranges)
```

Answer (score 1):

To have an iterable object from the list of iterable form the different ranges you can use the `chain` function as in the following response https://stackoverflow.com/a/67547449/1287983.

And in order to have dynamic ranges in a function you can do the following:

```
def get_ranges(list_ranges):
    lower_bounds, upper_bounds = zip(*list_ranges)
    return list(chain(*list(map(
        range, lower_bounds, upper_bounds))))

get_ranges([(1,2), (4,6), (10,13)])
```

> [1, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12]

The function above returns the list of values. And if you want to iterate efficiently over the resulting values, you just need to return the iterator instead of the list. See the code below.

```
def get_ranges(list_ranges):
    lower_bounds, upper_bounds = zip(*list_ranges)
    return chain(*list(map(range, lower_bounds, upper_bounds)))

for val in get_ranges([(1,2), (4,6), (10,13), (2,5)]):
    print(val)
```

> 1
> 4
> 5
> 10
> 11
> 12
> 2
> 3
> 4

Comment: How can this be used in a for loop?

Comment: @mufty__py  I edited the response by adding the way to use the result in a for loop.